# Create an instance of the Custom HTML module from within my component J4

Tags: joomla-4.x, mod-custom

I'm trying to adapt the solution @FFrewin provided for J3 ([Generate and render a module on an article with PHP](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/24590/generate-and-render-a-module-on-an-article-with-php/24595#24595)) to enable me to create an instance of the mod_custom record with contents provided by my component upon creating a new record.  The following code is what I'm trying without success, so any guidance would be appreciated.

```
public static function createModule($data, $params)
{
    $doc = Factory::getDocument();
    // Use a module title, so you won't load an existing module from the database then rename it.
    $module = ModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom', 'Custom PHP Generated Instance');
    $module->style = "System-html5";
    $module->title = $data['title'];
    $module->position = '';
    $module->showtitle = "0";
    $module->content = "This is the content of the PHP generated instance of mod_custom";

    // Module Params
    $moduleParams = new Registry($module->params);
    $moduleParams->set('style', "System-html5");
    $moduleParams->set('moduleclass_sfx', " center");

    //Render the module
    $renderer = $doc->loadRenderer('module');
    $moduleContent = $renderer->render($module, array('params'=> $moduleParams));
    // tried this as well
    //ModuleHelper::renderModule($module, array('params'=> $moduleParams));
    return $module->id;

}
```

Comment: What is or isn't working for you? Are then any messages or can you elaborate on what 'without success' means?

Comment: I don't get any error messages, but I don't get a module->id reference returned and there is no record in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In J4, `Factory::getDocument()` is deprecated and module rendering is accomplished through the `ModuleHelper`. I have not tried the adapted J3 code that you are using, but it should work, just maybe not as you're expecting.

Example J4 code that is working for me:

```
$module = ModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom', 'Custom PHP Generated Instance');
$module->title = $data['title'];
$module->position = '';
$module->showtitle = "0";
$module->content = "This is the content of the PHP generated instance of mod_custom";
$module->params = ['style'=>"System-html5",'moduleclass_sfx'=>" center"];

$html = ModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

`$module->params` can be a `Registry`, `object`, `array` or json_encoded string, whichever is easiest for you. It gets converted to a `Registry` when the module is rendered.

This code will not generate a `$module->id`, it will be set to `0`, nor will it create a record in the database. The module is created on the fly for immediate use and will need to be recreated each time it is needed.

You can return `$html` from the above code and then `echo` that wherever you need it displayed.

If you want to save the module, then you you should be able to hook in to `\Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Model\ModuleModel`. Just replace the last line of the above code with:

```
/** @var \Joomla\Component\Modules\Administrator\Model\ModuleModel $model */
$model = Factory::getApplication()->bootComponent('com_modules')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Module','Administrator');
$model->save($module);
$module->id = $model->getState('module.id');
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks Matt for the clarification.  This makes sense in a way.  So because I want to actually create the instance of the module I'll have to do this directly into the database.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a method for saving the module

Comment: Thank you for this, that helps a lot, although I must confess I'm starting to rethink if in fact I need to actually save it.  Thinking of the whys and wherefores of just generating it each time I want it displayed.  Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Ok, here's a question, can I specify the position of the module to display in? ie $module->position = 'top-a'; so that the module will display in the template position called "top-a"?  Actually I'm guessing not because the main component area is after the rendering of positions before it?